# Segmentations error

Tags: c++, linked-list

I am new to programming. I wrote the following program to swap the two consecutive numbers in a list using linked list. For eg. 1 2 3 4 5 6 will appear as 2 1 4 3 6 5. But as it turns out there is no error while compiling but when this code runs it doesn't give the required update. Can anyone please help me out here?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct node{
    int data;
    node *next;
};


int main(){
    node* head;
    head=NULL;
    node *temp= new node;
    temp->data=1;
    temp->next=NULL;
    head=temp;
    int p=2;
    while(p%6!=0){
        node* temp1= new node;
        temp1->data=p;
        temp1->next=NULL;
        temp->next=temp1;
        temp=temp->next;
        p++;
    }
    node* t1=new node;
    t1=head;
    while(t1!=NULL){
        cout<<t1->data<<endl;
        t1=t1->next;
    }
    t1=head;
    node* t2=new node;
    t2=t1->next;
    cout<<p;
    while(t1!=NULL || t1->next!=NULL){
        p=t1->data;
        cout<<p;
        t1->data=t2->data;
        t2->data=p;
        t1=t1->next->next;
    }
    t1=head;
    while(t1!=NULL){
        cout<<t1->data<<endl;
        t1=t1->next;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried to [debug your small program](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)?

Comment: Your next-to-last loop advances `t1`, but never touches `t2`.

Answer (score 0):

Using this loop

```
while(p%6!=0){
    node* temp1= new node;
    temp1->data=p;
    temp1->next=NULL;
    temp->next=temp1;
    temp=temp->next;
    p++;
}
```

you will not get the node with data equal to 6.:) When p will be equal to 6 the loop will not be iterated.

In these statements there is a memory leak

```
node* t1=new node;
t1=head;
```

because you at first assign the address of the new allocated memory to t1 and then reasssign it with head.

The same bug exists in these statements

```
node* t2=new node;
t2=t1->next;
```

There is incorrect condition in this loop

```
while(t1!=NULL || t1->next!=NULL){
```

There has to be

```
while(t1!=NULL && t1->next!=NULL){
```

or

```
while(t1!=NULL && t2!=NULL){
```

Also inside the body of the loop you do not reassign t2.

Here is a sample that does the same that you are trying to do

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

struct node
{
    int data;
    node *next;
};

int main() 
{
    node *head = NULL;
    node **tmp = &head;

    for ( int i = 1; i <= 6; i++ )
    {
        *tmp = new node { i, NULL };
        tmp = &( *tmp )->next;
    }

    for ( tmp = &head; *tmp; tmp = &( *tmp )->next  )
    {
        std::cout << ( *tmp )->data << ' ';
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;

    for ( tmp = &head; *tmp && ( *tmp )->next; tmp = &( *tmp )->next->next )
    {
        std::swap( ( *tmp )->data, ( *tmp )->next->data );
    }

    for ( tmp = &head; *tmp; tmp = &( *tmp )->next  )
    {
        std::cout << ( *tmp )->data << ' ';
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;

    tmp = &head;
    while ( *tmp )
    {
        node *current = *tmp;
        tmp = &( *tmp )->next;
        delete current;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The output is

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 
2 1 4 3 6 5
```

Comment: int main(){
 struct node* head= NULL;
 int p=1;
 while(p%7!=0){
  head= append(p, head);
  p++;
 }
 print(head);
 cout<<12;
 swap(head);
 print(head);
 return 0;
} //after my first print(head) it doesn't move forward, so i figured out there must be something wrong with the print function only please tell me what am i doing wrong void print(node* p){
 if(p==NULL)
  return;
 cout<<p->data<<endl;
 print(p->next);
}

Comment: @Ankit Parashar I do not know how you defined functions append, print and swap so I can say nothing.